# Stop action in view when uinavigationcontroller clicked back to previous view on iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I have a uinavigationcontroller with 2 views.  In the second view I have some audio playing.  When I click the back navigation item on the navigation bar the audio still plays.  How do I end the process of anything happening in the second view when the user clicks back to the initial view.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the 2nd view's [viewWillDisappear](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillDisappear:) method to stop the music